# Explanation of the derivation of the analytical gradient for a SVM?

Tags: svm, gradient-descent, gradient

I'm trying to understand how to derive the analytical gradient for a SVM.

I know that in a SVM, the loss function is defined as follows:

[image: Loss function]

From [this blogpost](https://mlxai.github.io/2017/01/06/vectorized-implementation-of-svm-loss-and-gradient-update.html), I know the full loss for each element in the weights matrix, $W$, is:

[image]

I know that the above turns into:

[image]

However, I don't quite understand the final step, which is that if $(x_iw_1 - x_iw_{y_i} + \Delta) > 0$ then we know:

$\frac{dL_i}{dw_{11}} = x_{i1}$

My guess is that the intuition is: The derivative of $x_{i1}w_{11}$ with respect to $w_{11}$ is $x_{i1}$, but I'm not sure.

Could someone help clarify what's going on here for me?